# Extjs Click event, double fire

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, casperjs

I'm playing with Casperjs and ExtJS

Here is my playground: http://jsfiddle.net/charlesbourasseau/fEDCu/

Here is my test.coffee:
    casper = require('casper').create
      logLevel: 'debug'
      verbose: true

```
url = 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/charlesbourasseau/fEDCu/show/'

casper.start url, ->

  @click '.x-btn'

casper.run -> @test.renderResults true
```

Here is the output:

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://fiddle.jshell.net/charlesbourasseau/fEDCu/show/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step 2/2 http://fiddle.jshell.net/charlesbourasseau/fEDCu/show/ (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: .x-btn
[info] [remote] Click!
[info] [remote] Click!
[info] [phantom] Step 2/2: done in 4146ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 2 steps in 4233ms
FAIL Looks like you didn't run any test.
```

Has someone an idea why I get 2 `[info] [remote] Click!` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a CasperJS issue, it's fix in the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about casperjs but your fiddle looks fine. If you click a button - you get one log entry.

Comment: casperjs is fine, I tested it with a fiddle without Extjs and only one entry was printed.